# applet loading in jsp dynamically

Tags: java, jquery, applet

I have the below applet in my code. I want to remove this code from jsp and include on click of button and remove after jQuery success.

```
<applet id="jzebra-applet" name="jZebra" code="jzebra.PrintApplet.class" archive="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jzebra.jar" width="1" height="1">
      <param name="printer" value="zebra">
</applet>
```

I am using jQuery and Struts2.

Thank you for your help in advance. Kindly let me know if any further information on my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, according to the Java 6 docs, the most appropriate way of calling an applet is by using a javascript supplied by Sun. That's because different browsers deal differently with an applet. Some want the EMBED tag, some want the APPLET tag and so on.

Having said that, if you follow their recommendation, it's just a matter of invoking the javascript in your on click event.

```
<script src="http://www.java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>
<script>
function runApplet(){
    var attributes = {
    code : 'jzebra.PrintApplet.class',
    archive : '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jzebra.jar',
    width : 500,
    height : 300
    };
    var parameters = {
    printer : 'zebra'
    };
    var version = '1.6';
    deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, version);
}
</script>
...
<h:commandButton value="Run applet" onclick="runApplet();" action="#"/>
```

I am using a commandButton from JSF here, but the same idea applies to whatever html-based presentation layer you're using.

Comment: This works very well, thanks. How do I unload once the task is complete?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Hide the applet after it executes? I haven't tried doing that, but I'd try to create a javascript function that hides the container that contains the applet (i.e., wrap the script bit in a div) and call that function from within the applet. Look up the documentation on how to invoke javascript from the applet code. I think that would work, I haven't tried it myself, though.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using the same JSP page as the template for displaying, you can place a Struts conditional tag in the page:

```
<s:if test="%{requestSuccessState == false}">

<applet id="jzebra-applet" name="jZebra" code="jzebra.PrintApplet.class" archive="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jzebra.jar" width="1" height="1">
      <param name="printer" value="zebra">
</applet>

</s:if>
```

Make sure to set requestSuccessState in your Action class.